# Keyboard Fn problem on  Samsung netbook

Tags: keyboard, slackware, netbook

I'm running Slackware Linux on a Samsung NC 110 netbook.

None of the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys work exept for the audio volume level keys.

Currently I can control the brightness of the display with this command:

`echo -n 6 > /sys/class/backlight/samsung/brightness`

I would like to use this netbook with a projector but I can't switch the display without the use of the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys. Is there an alternate way to send the display to a projector without using the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys?

Thanks

Comment: How much do the keys not-work? If you run `xev | grep -i key` and press your Fn-SwitchDisplay combination, do you get any output?

Comment: No, it gives an output only with F11, F12, Pause and volume controls.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with `xrandr` to enable another display output.

If you're using a desktop environment (KDE, GNOME, XFCE), most likely it has a configuration tool to enable the video output and configure the resolution.